# UTC Time Assignment in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, date-format, utc

Does anyone have a simple means in VBScript to get the current time in UTC?

Thanx,
Chris

Comment: Do you mean local system time in UTC format?

Answer (score 17):

I use a simple technique

```
Set dateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")    
dateTime.SetVarDate (now())
wscript.echo  "Local Time:  " & dateTime
wscript.echo  "UTC Time: " & dateTime.GetVarDate (false)
```

[More info on SWbemDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you wanted to convert UTC back to local time do this:

```
Set dateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
        dateTime.SetVarDate now(),false  REM Where now is the UTC date
        wscript.echo cdate(dateTime.GetVarDate (true))
```

Comment: Is this present in every windows installation?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of examples out there. If you can access the registry this one will work for you:

```
od = now() 
set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
atb = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\" &_ 
    "Control\TimeZoneInformation\ActiveTimeBias" 
offsetMin = oShell.RegRead(atb) 
nd = dateadd("n", offsetMin, od) 
Response.Write("Current = " & od & "<br>UTC = " & nd)
```

From http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/date-time-routines-manipulation/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-gmt-time.html

Comment: How about in seconds?  I tried to change the "n" to "s" and it didn't change format....

Answer (score 1):

You can get time bias from [Win32_TimeZone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) `WMI` class.

```
myDate = "9/4/2013 17:23:08"
For Each objItem In GetObject(_
    "winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2").ExecQuery(_
    "Select * from Win32_TimeZone")
    bias = objItem.Bias
Next
myDate = DateAdd("n", bias, myDate)
WScript.Echo myDate
```

Answer (score 0):

With SetVarDate the offset change due to transition to daylight saving time (from +060 to +120) occurred one hour too soon. The RegRead(HKLM\..\ActiveTimeBias) method was spot-on. If reproduction is desired, just put the pc clock on a time just before and just after the expected transition time and check the results.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that formats the date to UTC as well. Note that you cannot format to a millesecond level with this.

```
Dim formattedDate 
Dim utcDate

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set dateTime = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")

dateTime.SetVarDate(now())
utcDate = dateTime.GetVarDate(false) 

wscript.echo  "Local Time:  " & dateTime
wscript.echo  "UTC Time: " & utcDate

formattedDate = DatePart("yyyy",utcDate) & "-" & Right("0" & DatePart("m",utcDate), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & DatePart("d",utcDate), 2) 
    & "T" & Right("0" & DatePart("h",utcDate), 2) & ":" & Right("0" & DatePart("n",utcDate), 2) 
    & ":" & Right("0" & DatePart("s",utcDate), 2) & ".000+0000"

wscript.echo formattedDate

'results in a format that looks like this: 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000

set dateTime=Nothing
set objShell=Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on above functions - returns a delta-value to be added to the current time to return UTC.

Or call it with DATE+TIME to return UTC.

Call it once and store in a global variable to offset any date/time to UTC.
Conversely Subtract it from any UTC to get the time in the current time zone.

The additional ROUND towards the bottom is an attempt to compensate for floating point errors in the conversion to the nearest second.

```
Function Time_add_To_get_UTC(Optional DateTime = 0) ''as double
    '' Returns value to add to current time to get to UTC
    ''Based on above functions : )
    ''return offset from current time to UTC
    ''https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887700/utc-time-assignment-in-vbscript/22842128
    Dim SWDT    ''As SWbemDateTime
    Dim dt          ''As Date
    
    Set SWDT = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
    
    dt = Date + Time()
    
    SWDT.SetVarDate (dt)
    
    Time_add_To_get_UTC = CDbl(SWDT.GetVarDate(False)) - CDbl(SWDT.GetVarDate(True))
    Time_add_To_get_UTC = CDbl(Round(Time_add_To_get_UTC * 24 * 60 * 60, 0) / 24 / 60 / 60)
    Time_add_To_get_UTC = DateTime + Time_add_To_get_UTC
End Function
```