# Msiexec /log with Datetime in UTC format

Tags: logging, wix, datetime-format, windows-installer

I build my own MSI from wsx code. When I run it with command

```
msiexec /i "test.msi" /quiet /norestart /qn /log "test.log"
```

I have log file like that

```
Action start 10:19:28: INSTALL.
Action start 10:19:28: FindRelatedProducts.
Action ended 10:19:28: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.
Action start 10:19:28: SaveCmdLineValueINSTALLDIR.
Action ended 10:19:28: SaveCmdLineValueINSTALLDIR. Return value 1.
Action start 10:19:28: AppSearch.
```

Date and Time in log file is local, but I need UTC format. Are there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick look and investigated the log for **`1)`** timestamps C style (no obvious ones) ([how to interpret an MSI log](https://web.archive.org/web/20080916030949/http://www.rmacdonald.members.winisp.net/Blog_Docs/Annotated_Windows_Installer_Log.pdf)), **`2)`** [the use of debugging logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890) also did not add much useful, then there is the issue of **`3)`** system policies - maybe they can report all times in UTC? Not sure. Didn't find anything obvious. Times in the **`4)`** [event viewer](https://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/logs/eventlog/default.asp) seem to be local time, but you might be able to access it to get UTC versions.

What you definitely can do is to **`5)`** [use a custom action](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/msi_writing_to_the_log_file.pdf) to write UTC time yourself directly into the start of the log. Would that help? ([UTC Time VBScript](https://www.vbsedit.com/scripts/os/dates/default.asp)).

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_UTCTime")

For Each objItem in colItems
  Msgbox "UTC Time: " + CStr(objItem.Hour) + CStr(":") + CStr(objItem.Minute) + CStr(":") + CStr(objItem.Second)
Next
```

---

***Custom Action Snippets***: Numerous constructs required in WiX source file to run VBScript custom actions:

```
<Binary Id='UTC.vbs' SourceFile='UTC.vbs' />
<CustomAction Id='UTC.vbs' VBScriptCall='' BinaryKey='UTC.vbs' Execute='immediate' Return='ignore'/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action='UTC.vbs' Sequence='1' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

---

***Write to Log***: [**How to write to the MSI log file**](https://resources.flexera.com/web/pdf/archive/msi_writing_to_the_log_file.pdf). The code required to write to the log file in terse form:

```
Const msiMessageTypeInfo = &H04000000
Set msgrec = Installer.CreateRecord(1) 
msgrec.StringData(0) = "Log: [1]"
msgrec.StringData(1) = "write this to log"
Session.Message msiMessageTypeInfo, msgrec
```

---

***Links***:

- [UTC Time Assignment in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887700/utc-time-assignment-in-vbscript)